# Command which retrieves previously sent messages in a channel using discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I've been searching the way(s) to do the below listed things using `@name_of_object.command()` .

- Retrieve messages in a channel in last x days.
- That retrieved messages are stored in an array with 3 arguments. Each element of that array contains 3 types of information, which are Message , who sent it, and when it was sent.

I searched for answers in [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html) and thought that [created_at](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.created_at) may be useful to achieve what I want to do. Can anyone tell me some hints or what websites I should look at?

What I've done:

I quoted the below code from [here](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/python/discord.py+get+message+text)

```
@bot.command()
async def getmsg(ctx, channel: discord.TextChannel, member: discord.Member):
    msg = discord.utils.get(await channel.history(limit=100).flatten(), author=member)
    # this gets the most recent message from a specified member in the past 100 messages
    # in a certain text channel - just an idea of how to use its versatility
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`channel.history`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.history) to retrieve messages filtered by date.

To do so, first obtain a [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html)-Object specifying the date after which you want to get messages (and, if you want, also up to which).
In your case, you should be able to use something like

```py
date = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=5)
```

In `date` we have now a `datetime`-Object representing five days ago.

As your next step you can retrieve all messages after that date using [`channel.history()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.history) and especially its `after`-parameter. This gives you an [`async iterator`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.AsyncIterator)-object to work with. Assuming your bot is named `bot` and you are using [`discord.ext.commands`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html), you could do something like

```py
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    channel = await bot.fetch_channel(YOUR_CHANNEL_ID)
    async for message in channel.history(after=date):
        print(message.created_at, message.author.name, message.content)
```

Remember to replace `YOUR_CHANNEL_ID` with the id of your textchannel (You can optain it via `Rightclick → Copy ID`). If you run your command in the same channel you want to get messages from, you could also use `ctx.channel` instead of fetching it by its id.

If you are just starting with discord commands, I would also suggest to have a look at [this introduction to commands](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html), which explains some basics in more detail (and the [API reference](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html) you already found).

Comment: Thank youu . I'm now trying codes with bit modified of your code.